# I want to make a random number selector but the result is higher than expected

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have a page full of random stuff and into those things I have a random number generator. I tried it but the result is higher than expected, somebody knows what? Here is my code:

```html
    <div>
        <h2>Get a random number</h2>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="inputMin" placeholder="Min" required autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" id="inputMax" placeholder="Max" required autocomplete="off">
        <br><br>
        <button id="randomNumberButton">Generate</button>
        <br>
        <span class="error" id="randomNumberError"></span>
        <span id="randomNumberResult"></span>
    </div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```js
    try {
        var randomNumberError = document.getElementById("randomNumberError")
        const randomNumberButton = document.getElementById("randomNumberButton")
        function getRandomNumber2(){
            var inputMin = document.getElementById("inputMin")
            var inputMax = document.getElementById("inputMax")
            const selector = getRandomNumber(inputMin.value, inputMax.value)
            console.log(inputMin.value, inputMax.value, selector);
            const result = document.getElementById("randomNumberResult")
            function removeRandomNumberError(){
                randomNumberError.textContent = ""
            }
            if (inputMin.value == "" || inputMax.value == ""){
                randomNumberError.textContent = "Both fields are required."
                inputMin.addEventListener("click", removeRandomNumberError)
                inputMax.addEventListener("click", removeRandomNumberError)
                return
            }
            if(isNaN(inputMin.value) || isNaN(inputMax.value)){
                randomNumberError.textContent = "Both values should be numbers"
                inputMin.addEventListener("click", removeRandomNumberError)
                inputMax.addEventListener("click", removeRandomNumberError)
                return
            }
            result.textContent = selector
        }
        randomNumberButton.addEventListener("click", getRandomNumber2)
    } catch (err){
        randomNumberError.textContent = err
    }
```

I would really appreciate if someone

Comment: For example, the first attempt was with 1 as mimimum and 10 as maximum, but one of the results was 81

Comment: We would need to see the code for `getRandomNumber()`. Also, please be aware you can edit your own question to add examples or more information, rather than scattering it in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution (working as I understood to your question):
html code (only changed input type to number)

```
<input type="number" id="inputMin" placeholder="Min" required autocomplete="off">
<input type="number" id="inputMax" placeholder="Max" required autocomplete="off">
```

and js code is:

```
var button = document.getElementById('randomNumberButton');
var result = document.getElementById('randomNumberResult');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var min = parseInt(document.getElementById('inputMin').value);
    var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('inputMax').value);

    result.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    alert(result.value);
});
```